# Display all rows in column with foreach

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I am trying to use foreach to echo every row in a column. But am getting:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$user = user;
$pass = pass;
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=onlyaskf_registered', $user, $pass);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*), sum(price),part_number,location,price FROM products WHERE code = :usercode");
$stmt->bindParam(':usercode', $_SESSION['MM_Username']);

?>

<?php 
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    foreach($stmt->fetchColumn(2) as $row) {
        echo $row;
    }
}  
?>
```

With this code I can get the first row within the column:

```
<?php 
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $row = $stmt->fetchColumn(2);
    echo $row;
}  
?>
```

Column 2 is my part_number column, if I format my php like above it gives me the first instance of that column's row. How do I get it to show each row in the column with foreach? Is that even possible or is there a better method to echo an entire column's rows?

UPDATE:

I changed my code to this but it is only giving me the first row's column value instead of every row:

```
<?php if ($stmt->execute()) {
while($val = $stmt->fetch()) { 
echo $val['part_number'];
}
}  ?>
```

Comment: `print_r($row)` u will get the idea how it will display

Comment: @devpro I changed echo $row; to print_r($row) this still gives me the same result though and am getting the Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: try same thing with @marc-b example

Comment: @devpro This gives me the entire Array like this: `Array ( [COUNT(*)] => 3[part_number] => 14124 [location] => here town` how can I set it so it displays ONLY all the rows in the `part_number` column?

Comment: now u can print it easily like `echo $val['part_number'];` or `echo $val['location']` same for count but not sure this will `$val['COUNT(*)']` work or not.

Comment: @devpro This is helpful, I am able to echo the `echo $val['part_number'];` but its still only giving me the first row in the column instead of every row. I'm sorry, im pretty new to PDO and PHP so if I seem dense I apologize.

Comment: are u using while loop or not?

Comment: @devpro yeah I have the while loop in there, I updated my code above. It is printing out the first column value, still not getting it to print every row in the column :(

Comment: not `print_r($val['part_number']);` use `echo $val['part_number'];`

Comment: @devpro Ok I changed it to that, I updated my code, I am still only getting the first row only

Comment: ok remove `sum(price)` and test

Comment: @devpro removed `sum(price)` still just showing the first row only

Comment: @devpro this might have actually worked, one sec..

Comment: @devpro this worked! If you answer the question I can mark this as answered

Comment: actually, SUM will return the result in group and u need all rows, so u need to use php for sum purpose, right

Comment: @devpro that was it, the SUM was grouping everything thats why I was only getting one row in the loop. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update, code is not giving you first row, it's giving you one row just because of `SUM()` function in your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), sum(price),part_number,location,price FROM products
```

*Note that, [`SUM()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) will returns the total sum of a numeric column.*

So, in your case, you need to remove `sum(price)` function from your query than you will get the all rows.

You can use PHP for this purpose something like:

```
$sum = 0;
while($val = $stmt->fetch()) { 
    $sum += $val['price'];
}
echo $sum; // will return sum of all rows.
```

Answer (score 1):

fetchColumn() doesn't return an array, so you can NOT foreach on it. You use `while` instead:

```
while($val = $stmt->fetchColumn(2)) { 
    echo $val;
}
```

But note that this FAILS if you're retrieving a boolean field. As per the note in the docs:

> Note:
>
> PDOStatement::fetchColumn() should not be used to retrieve boolean columns, as it is impossible to distinguish a value of FALSE from
>   there being no more rows to retrieve. Use PDOStatement::fetch()
>   instead.

Comment: this cleared up the warning I was getting, it now outputs a value that says 'Array' after switching to fetch(). How can I get this to echo the column's rows?

Comment: @holodout: now u can chk the `print_r($val)` `$val` is an array so when u try to echo array it will always give u `Array` :) and i already mentioned in comment test same with this example

Comment: fetch() DOES return an array... you REALLY need to learn how to read the docs, and not just blindly regurgitate code.